# ROS Answers SE migration: Mapping robot

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

What is needed to make a keyboard - driven robot (w - a - s - d) with 2 motors + encoders, which is capable of creating maps with 360 laser scans (RPLIDAR)? Should the robot Subscribe msg / cmd_vel and publish msg / odom, msg / laser_scan to RVIZ? anything else?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314282/mapping-robot/) by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2019-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You've come to the right place. This tutorial will do everything you're asking. Take your time and work through it slowly. That will be much faster than trying to skim it and take short cuts.

http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2019-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1